# What part of a sentence is "regarding X" classified as?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In the process of learning Japanese, I've been doing some grammar analysis on sentence structure (across languages), Eg. subject, object, etc. I've come across something I haven't heard of before: the "topic" of the sentence.

Take this sentence:
"Regarding coffee, arabica is smooth."
"Arabica" is the subject, and in Japanese, "coffee" would be called the topic.

I can't find anything on the term "topic" as a classification of a part of a sentence in English. How is this defined in English?

Comment: "Topic" is a term that makes a lot more sense in Japanese grammar than in English. Whatever gets the _wa_ marker is the topic, and often it's the subject, but _wa_ and _ga_ are different.

Comment: Indeed, I understand the *wa*-marked topic is a non-logical particle (will never change the logic of the sentence, only emphasize something as a topic) and that, even when the topic and subject are identical, there's still a hidden, implied *ga* subject with the same noun/pronoun but isn't (redundantly) spoken. Regardless, though, we do still have those phrases that mean the same thing in English (Eg. "regarding __," "as for __," etc.) So in English grammar, how do we define such phrases in terms of "parts of a sentence"?

Comment: In English grammar, they're called a number of things, usually by form or function - prepositional phrases, conversational linkers, etc.

Comment: I use the functional classification: _pragmatic marker, discourse related, topic focusing_. It's a parenthetical, here fronting the main clause.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/regarding) defines "regarding" in this context as a preposition (although I'm sure there are reasons for questioning that classification). You can compare other prepositions like [re](https://www.lexico.com/definition/re).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum (2002), "regarding coffee" is a **domain adjunct** consisting of a prepositional phrase.